# Can someone explain the difference between these two codes ? Code is to find the sum of deepest leaves in tree

Tags: c++, tree, sum

This is a Leetcode question

```
int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode* root) {
            int res=0;
            int i;
            queue<TreeNode*> q;
            q.push(root);
            while(!q.empty()){
                for(i = q.size()-1,res=0;i>=0;i--){
                    TreeNode* temp = q.front();
                    q.pop();
                    res += temp->val;
                    if(temp->left)q.push(temp->left);
                    if(temp->right)q.push(temp->right);
                }
            }
            
            return res;
        }
```

VS

```
int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode* root) {
        int res=0;
       // int i;
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            for(int i = q.size()-1,res=0;i>=0;i--){
                TreeNode* temp = q.front();
                q.pop();
                res += temp->val;
                if(temp->left)q.push(temp->left);
                if(temp->right)q.push(temp->right);
            }
        }
        
        return res;
    }
```

the first one gives correct ans while the second one does not. Can someone tell me why declaring the int i outside is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second, you have defined both `i` and `res` as local variables in the loop:

```
for(int i = q.size()-1, res = 0; i >= 0; i--)
```

This hides the `int res = 0;` definition at the top of the function.  And so when the loop exits, `res` is still zero.

In the first example, you reset `res` to zero every time around the while-loop.  While it's not clear whether this is *correct*, the equivalent thing to do in your second example (for identical behavior as the first) is to explicitly set `res` to zero before the for-loop and do not declare it as a local loop variable:

```
res = 0;
for(int i = q.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```